# Do Android Q and R file permission restrictions apply to NDK code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-permissions

Android Q and R have progressively more restrictive file permission restrictions. You can no longer access anything you want on SDCARD and anything you do want to access must be gotten through a FileProvider.

This is true in Java/Kotlin, but what about C++ in the NDK?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no exception for NDK code. This is one of the major issues that got brought up when these changes were announced.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That's going to cause issues for a number of apps I'm sure...